# Add additional columns to the Customer List on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add more columns to the WooCommerce > under the WooCommerce tab called Customer List.
I want to add columns phone number (billing phone number) and remove any fields if i want.

Any help is appreciated.

My code so far but it doesn't work.

```
// Add custom columns to WooCommerce Customer List
function add_custom_columns_to_customer_list($columns) {
    $columns['billing_phone'] = 'Phone Number';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_customer_columns', 'add_custom_columns_to_customer_list');

// Populate custom columns with data
function populate_custom_columns($column, $customer_id) {
    if ($column === 'billing_phone') {
        $customer = new WC_Customer($customer_id);
        echo $customer->get_billing_phone();
    }
}
add_action('manage_shop_customer_posts_custom_column', 'populate_custom_columns', 10, 2);

// Remove existing columns from WooCommerce Customer List
function remove_existing_columns($columns) {
    unset($columns['billing_address']); // Remove billing address column
    unset($columns['shipping_address']); // Remove shipping address column
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_customer_columns', 'remove_existing_columns', 20);

// Adjust column order
function reorder_columns($columns) {
    $new_columns = array();

    // Add desired columns in the desired order
    $new_columns['cb'] = $columns['cb'];
    $new_columns['username'] = $columns['username'];
    $new_columns['email'] = $columns['email'];
    $new_columns['billing_phone'] = $columns['billing_phone'];
    $new_columns['actions'] = $columns['actions'];

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_customer_columns', 'reorder_columns', 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I add a column from user meta data identified by meta_key 'CodCli'.

The first step is modify de query clauses.

```
function gnxo_add_join_subquery( $clauses ) {
    global $wpdb;
 
    $clauses[] = "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} codcli_meta ON {$wpdb->prefix}wc_customer_lookup.user_id = codcli_meta.user_id and codcli_meta.meta_key = 'CodCli' ";
 
    return $clauses;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_analytics_clauses_join_customers_subquery', 'gnxo_add_join_subquery' );

function gnxo_add_select_subquery( $clauses ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $clauses[0] = str_replace('user_id',"{$wpdb->prefix}wc_customer_lookup.user_id",$clauses[0]);

    $clauses[] = ', codcli_meta.meta_value AS codcli';
 
    return $clauses;
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_analytics_clauses_select_customers_subquery', 'gnxo_add_select_subquery' );
```

It's important to disable de cache to ensure execution of analytics clauses hooks.

```
function gnxo_should_cache($cache,$key){
    if ($key === 'customers'){
        return false;
    }
    return $cache;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_analytics_report_should_use_cache',"gnxo_should_cache",10,2);
```

The second step is in javascript code, I created *admin.js* file whith the following code

```
const addTableColumn = reportTableData => {
    if ( 'customers' !== reportTableData.endpoint ) {
        return reportTableData;
    }
 
    const newHeaders = [
        {
            label: admin_params.identifier,
            key: 'codcli',
        },
        ...reportTableData.headers,
    ];
    const newRows = reportTableData.rows.map( ( row, index ) => {
        const item = reportTableData.items.data[ index ];
        const newRow = [
            {
                display: item.codcli,
                value: item.codcli,
            },
            ...row,
        ];
        return newRow;
    } );
 
    reportTableData.headers = newHeaders;
    reportTableData.rows = newRows;
 
    return reportTableData;
};
 
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'woocommerce_admin_report_table', 'gnxo-ofertas', addTableColumn );
```

This script depends from *wp-hooks* so I enqueue and localize the new file using this code.

```
wp_enqueue_script('gnxofertas_admin',gnxo_plugin_url('/assets/js/admin.js'),['wp-hooks'],false,['in_footer']);
wp_localize_script('gnxofertas_admin','admin_params',['identifier' => __('Identifier','gnxo-oferta')]);
```

*gnxo_plugin_url* is a function to get the absolute url from my plugin.

I hope this code can help.